# Cannot find column 63

Tags: c#

The piece of code,

```
string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO Planilha
(
  ROTALOJ     , ROTA      , LOJA          , [BAIRRO-LOJA] , UF           ,
  [INI-R]     , [FIN-R]   , DOCA          , [D-GER]       , [H-GER]      ,
  [FIN-P]     , [FIN-P1]  , [INI-S]       , [INI-S1]      , [FIN-S]      ,
  [FIN-S1]    , [HR-SE]   , [D-CON]       , [H-CON]       , [D-DOC]      ,
  [H-DOC]     , [D-EMI]   , [H-EMI]       , [D-SAI]       , [H-SAI]      ,
  [Q-PER]     , [LOJ-E]   , [LOJ-E1]      , [LOJ-P]       , [LOJ-P1]     ,
  PLACA       , [TP-VEIC] , [NOME-GUERRA] , MOTORIST      , [T-DES]      ,
  [T-SEP]     , [S-LOJ]   , [S-LOJ1]      , [H-DES]       , [TP-CARG]    ,
  DEP         , BD        , PESO          , VOLUME        , [VAL-TRANSF] ,
  [VAL-FRETE] , [PLC-CAV] , RG            , LIBER         , LIBER1       ,
  DTFLY       , QTFLV     , DTOUT         , QTOUT         , [SE-RI]      ,
  [SE-RI1]    , [SE-RF]   , [SE-RF1]      , DTPER         , QTPER        ,
  SEQ         , FA        , [D-SEN]
)
VALUES
(
  @p0+@p1     , @p0       , @p1          , @p2            , @p3  ,
  @p4         , @p5       , @p6          , @p7            , @p8  ,
  @p9         , @p10      , @p11         , @p12           , @p13 ,
  @p14        , @p15      , @p16         , @p17           , @p18 ,
  @p19        , @p20      , @p21         , @p22           , @p23 ,
  @p24        , @p25      , @p26         , @p27           , @p28 ,
  @p29        , @p30      , @p31         , @p32           , @p33 ,
  @p34        , @p35      , @p36         , @p37           , @p38 ,
  @p39        , @p40      , @p41         , @p42           , @p43 ,
  @p44        , @p45      , @p46         , @p47           , @p48 ,
  @p49        , @p50      , @p51         , @p52           , @p53 ,
  @p54        , @p55      , @p56         , @p57           , @p58 ,
  @p59        , @p60      , @p61         , @p62                   
)
";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conexao);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", dtExcel.Rows[i][0]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dtExcel.Rows[i][1]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dtExcel.Rows[i][2]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", dtExcel.Rows[i][3]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", dtExcel.Rows[i][4]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", dtExcel.Rows[i][5]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", dtExcel.Rows[i][6]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", dtExcel.Rows[i][7]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", dtExcel.Rows[i][8]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", dtExcel.Rows[i][9]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", dtExcel.Rows[i][10]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", dtExcel.Rows[i][11]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", dtExcel.Rows[i][12]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", dtExcel.Rows[i][13]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", dtExcel.Rows[i][14]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", dtExcel.Rows[i][15]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p16", dtExcel.Rows[i][16]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p17", dtExcel.Rows[i][17]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p18", dtExcel.Rows[i][18]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p19", dtExcel.Rows[i][19]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p20", dtExcel.Rows[i][20]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p21", dtExcel.Rows[i][21]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p22", dtExcel.Rows[i][22]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p23", dtExcel.Rows[i][23]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p24", dtExcel.Rows[i][24]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p25", dtExcel.Rows[i][25]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p26", dtExcel.Rows[i][26]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p27", dtExcel.Rows[i][27]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p28", dtExcel.Rows[i][28]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p29", dtExcel.Rows[i][29]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p30", dtExcel.Rows[i][30]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p31", dtExcel.Rows[i][31]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p32", dtExcel.Rows[i][32]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p33", dtExcel.Rows[i][33]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p34", dtExcel.Rows[i][34]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p35", dtExcel.Rows[i][35]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p36", dtExcel.Rows[i][36]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p37", dtExcel.Rows[i][37]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p38", dtExcel.Rows[i][38]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p39", dtExcel.Rows[i][39]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p40", dtExcel.Rows[i][40]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p41", dtExcel.Rows[i][41]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p42", dtExcel.Rows[i][42]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p43", dtExcel.Rows[i][43]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p44", dtExcel.Rows[i][44]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p45", dtExcel.Rows[i][45]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p46", dtExcel.Rows[i][46]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p47", dtExcel.Rows[i][47]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p48", dtExcel.Rows[i][48]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p49", dtExcel.Rows[i][49]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p50", dtExcel.Rows[i][50]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p51", dtExcel.Rows[i][51]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p52", dtExcel.Rows[i][52]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p53", dtExcel.Rows[i][53]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p54", dtExcel.Rows[i][54]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p55", dtExcel.Rows[i][55]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p56", dtExcel.Rows[i][56]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p57", dtExcel.Rows[i][57]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p58", dtExcel.Rows[i][58]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p59", dtExcel.Rows[i][59]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p60", dtExcel.Rows[i][60]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p61", dtExcel.Rows[i][61]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p62", dtExcel.Rows[i][62]);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

is now giving this error...

[image: Error screen]

for those who help me thank you I'm waiting for the answer from someone

DB

```
ROTALOJ varchar(50) Checked
ROTA    varchar(50) Checked
LOJA    varchar(50) Checked
```

Comment: A quick check gives me that you're trying to insert 64 values (p0+p1,p0,...,p62) into 63 columns... may have got the count wrong but it'd be consistent with the message.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't loop through your rows and add a new parameter for each?  It would be a hell of a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement specifies 63 columns and your value list is supplying 64 columns.

I've reflowed your code sample for clarity. The problem should be fairly obvious.

For what it's worth, especially with SQL, tidy, tabular code is a huge cognitive help. People's minds understand regularity and notice irregularity.

Also, remember the DRY principle ("Don't Repeat Yourself"): a simple loop, instead of the same thing repeated 63 times is preferred:

```
for ( int j = 0 ; j < 63 ; ++i )
{
    string name  = string.Format("@p{0}",j) ;
    object value = dtExcel.Rows[i][j] ;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( name , value );
}
```